# The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a query in EF where there is a List of string value that it checks for existence in another table.

Please consider the below query for more details.

**Code**

```
List<string> ItmsStock = item.Select(ds => ds.ItemNum).ToList(); // Currently, This List items count is 80,000 records.
this.Db.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
var existsStckList = Db.Stocktakes.Where(ds => ItmsStock.Contains(ds.ItemNo)).Select(ds => ds.ItemNo).ToList();
item.RemoveAll(ds => existsStckList.Contains(ds.ItemNum));
var ItmsExists = Db.Items.Where(ds => ItmsStock.Contains(ds.ItemNo)).Select(ds => ds.ItemNo).ToList();
ItmsExists = Db.Stocktakes.Where(ds => !ItmsExists.Contains(ds.ItemNo)).Select(ds => ds.ItemNo).ToList();
```

I searched on the internet and found the converted sql uses `IN` to check for existence. so, the limit for the `IN` makes the problem. My question here is, How can I efficiently perform the above actions without using for loop.

I ll be appreciating you, If anybody can help me out.

**Edit**

Previously, I had the below code. After facing the performance issue with the below code, I wrote the above one.

```
foreach (var stockitems in item)
{
   if (Db.Stocktakes.Any(a => a.ItemNo == stockitems.ItemNum))
   {
      StockResult ss = new StockResult();
      ss.ItemNumber = stockitems.ItemNum;
      ss.FileName = stockitems.FileName;
      Stockres.Add(ss);

   }
   else if (!Db.Stocktakes.Any(a => a.ItemNo == stockitems.ItemNum) && Db.Items.Any(a => a.ItemNo == stockitems.ItemNum))
   {
      var ItemNo = stockitems.ItemNum;
      var AdminId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["AccId"]);
      var CreatedOn = System.DateTime.Now;
      int dbres = Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into Stocktake values({0},{1},{2})", ItemNo, AdminId, CreatedOn);
      Db.SaveChanges();
      totalcount = totalcount + 1;
   }
   else
   {
      StockResult sss = new StockResult();
      sss.ItemNumber = stockitems.ItemNum;
      sss.FileName = stockitems.FileName;
      Stockitemsdup.Add(sss);
   }
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue batches of 1000 item IDs to the database, or use native SQL and submit a table-valued parameter, or a temp table filled with `SqlBulkCopy`.

I'm surprised you got htis particular message. The parameter limit is about 2000 parameters. Your query should have been rejected.